# Suvival Analysis - Need Help with Converting SAS code to RStudio

Tags: r, survival, sas

In the past I have used the following SAS code to perform survival analysis for the purpose of predicting retirement.

```
proc lifereg data=survive.combined;
model Years_of_Service*censor(1) = Unemployment_Rate Pension_Plan Newhire Disabled Female Office Salary / DIST=weibull ;
output out=New cdf=Prob predicted=pred_years_of_service q=0.90; 
run;
```

I am struggling with finding the RStudio equivalent to line 4 in this code:

```
output out=New cdf=Prob predicted=pred_years_of_service q=0.90;
```

My ultimate objective is to subtract the individual observation values of my dependent variable (`Years_Of_Service`) value from the variable `pred_years_of_service` which I am generating in line 4 and look at the difference between the two as an indicator of when someone may retire from the company.

Comment: RStudio is an IDE.  It is not a language.

Comment: See "SAS to R Tutorial" in 3 parts, starting from https://gallery.azure.ai/Notebook/SAS-to-R-Tutorial-Part-1-1

Comment: Frank, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not address my issue, but it's a good source of information.